# Repeating code fragments in XML editor

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make an XML editor. So far, I got the results I wanted, but a lot of code is repeated. How can I reuse more effectively?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XmlUtil {
    private static File fXmlFile;
    private static DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    private static DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    private static Document doc;

    public static ObservableList<String> getAllTagText(String fileName)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        ObservableList<String> tagList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        fXmlFile = new File(fileName);
        doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Tag");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            String tag = nodeList.item(i).getTextContent();
            tagList.add(tag);
        }

        return tagList;
    }

    public static String getLanguageText(String fileName, String tag,
            String language) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
            IOException {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        fXmlFile = new File(fileName);
        doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TEXT");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;
                if (element.getElementsByTagName("Tag").item(0)
                        .getTextContent().equals(tag)) {
                    return element.getElementsByTagName(language).item(0)
                            .getTextContent();

                }
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void setText(String fileName, String tag, String textContent)
            throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException,
            TransformerException {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        fXmlFile = new File(fileName);
        doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("TEXT");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node;
                if (element.getElementsByTagName("Tag").item(0)
                        .getTextContent().equals(tag)) {
                    element.getElementsByTagName("Hungarian").item(0)
                            .setTextContent(textContent);
                }

            }
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                    .newInstance();

            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);

            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(fXmlFile);
            transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[XPath](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/) does away with much of the very low-level w3c classes. And is within java SE: **javax.xml.xpath.XPath**.